# How to reference another nested class from within nested class

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

I have the following nested structure:

```
from peewee import *

class Parent:
    ...
    class A:
        name = TextField()

    class B:
        from_A = ForeignKeyField(A)
```

I am trying to reference class A within a ForeignKeyField within class B, but both `A` and `Parent.A` return a name not found error. What is the proper way to reference class A from within class B? Is this possible?

Comment: don't use nested classes.

Comment: @Daniel - I agree that in this case it would seem that nested Classes are the wrong solution, but there are cases where nested classes can be a good solution. I think it is a bad idea to suggest a blanket ban - if that is what you are trying to say.

Comment: Maybe present an [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of definition of class B, class Parent is not fully defined so it cannot be used: at definition time, you can only use:

- global variables
- variables belonging to the element being defined

But you have no access to variables defined in an enclosing block be them classes or not.

So you are left with only two options:

- define class B outside of Parent
- initialize the element at run time after everything has been defined (in that sense, run time starts immediately the end of the `class Parent` block`):

  ```
  class Parent:
      ...
      class A:
          name = TextField()

      class B:
           ...

  Parent.B.from_A = ForeignKeyField(Parent.A)
  ```